# How to change the whole range style when condition changed?

Tags: google-sheets

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hf2GURc8eYEOzImX4qIySH0IpDGe_7TedU6de4Xxa4o/edit?usp=sharing) is example link to Google Excel.

If the checkbox checked,the range `C1:E6` 
will change the style.

But when changed,it doesn't meet the result,only one cell be changed.

How do I set or add something to let the **whole range** changed when condition changed?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **custom formula: `=$B$1=TRUE`**
- **range: `C1:E6`**

[image]

Comment: Isn't the "$"symbol only meaning to absolute position at the Excel?

Comment: yes it does but now you (absolute) locking the red color for every cell in c1:e6

Comment: I don't understand.
What's the relationship between the $(absolute) and "lock"?

Comment: dunno, wordplay... when you absolute reference to the cell, it's like you locking on the cell or lock down the cell so your formula will always look on that "locked cell" even if you move your formula. hence that lock relationship.